# Graph with fixed amount of spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

"Find a graph with 8 vertices, which have exactly 27 spanning trees." How do I find such a graph, or prove one does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

27 = 3*3*3, so maybe we have to work with triangles. A triangle has three spanning trees. Let's take three triangles and try to connect them in such a way that we get 27 spanning trees and 8 edges.

Call them triangle A, B, C.

Connect triangle A and B together so that they share a vertex. Now we have 8 vertices. Connect a vertex from triangle C to the shared vertex of triangle A and B through an edge. Now we have 3*3*3 spanning trees.

I realize my description might be confusing so this may be more clear:
[image: a tree with 27 spanning trees, 8 vertices]

Comment: It was clear enough, but thank you anyway :)